# Print two appearances of character found in python list

Tags: python, list

First time here (and a programming noob), hope I get the formatting correct!

I'm trying to make a function that will print out where in a list the occurence of a sought after letter is placed. The code below finds the letter and prints out where in the list the letter is i.e. if you search for 'a' the program will answer it's in the 2nd spot (x+1).

The problem is, if I search for a letter that have more than one occurrencies (for example the letter 'e'), the program finds the letter in both spots but in both cases prints out that it is in the 10th spot.

I'm trying to find out why, should be 10th and 17th in this case.

```
# store string in variable
solution = list('can you guess me')
guess = raw_input('What letter do you guess on? ')

# Search list
def search(guess):
  nothing = 0
  for x in solution:
      if x == guess: 
          print x, 
          print "is in ", 
          print solution.index(x) + 1
          nothing = 1

  if nothing == 0:
      print "Couldn't find ", 
      print guess

search(guess)
```

If choosing e, like this:

```
What letter do you think is in the answer?  e
```

the program prints out:

```
e is in  11
e is in  11
```

I would like to know why. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Why is this function not returning the index for white space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199949/python-why-is-this-function-not-returning-the-index-for-white-space)

Comment: Just so you know, strings are already iterables in Python. You don't need to cast them to lists (first line), and `.index()` also works on strings.

Answer (score 3):

How about this approach:

```
solution = 'This is the solution'

# Search list
def search(guess):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(solution) if x == guess]

guess = raw_input('Enter your guess: ')
result = search(guess)
if result:
   positions = ','.join(str(i+1) for i in result)
   print('{0} was found in positions {1}'.format(guess, positions))
else:
   print('Sorry, {0} was not found!'.format(guess))
```

What we are doing here is stepping through the solution and if a character matches the guess, we return its position. If no characters match, then the method will return an empty list; which is a *falsey* value.

Then, we just check the return value of the method. If it is a list, we add 1 to the position (since list indices start from 0), and then print those out.

Answer (score 2):

`solution.index(x)` does the same search for you, but will only ever return the *first* match.

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead to create an index:

```
for i, x in enumerate(solution):
    if x == guess: 
        print x, 
        print "is in ", 
        print i + 1
        nothing = 1
```

The alternative approach would be to tell `solution.index()` where to start searching from. The previous position you printed, for example:

```
last = -1
for x in solution:
    if x == guess: 
        print x, 
        print "is in ", 
        last = solution.index(x, last) + 1
        print last 
        nothing = 1
```

Comment: Ah, need to learn more about basically all built-in functions. Thanks a ton! (Now I just have to figure out what the 'i, x in ...' modification mean, hehe!)

Comment: @Bigge: `enumerate()` gives you a sequence of `(index, originalvalue)` tuples, and the `i, x` is a *target list*; Python unpacks every tuple into those two names for you when the `for` loop assigns the next entry in the sequence.

Comment: @Bigge: You could also do `for index_value_pair in enumerate(solution):` and then use `i = index_value_pair[0]` and `x = index_value_pair[1]` but that is more verbose than needed.